# EF Core Shared Domain Project

Tags: c#, .net-core, database-design, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have a base Domain Project that has base classes for multiple projects to use.

Inside this base proj I have the following classes

```
public abstract class CommonUserAccount : IdentityUser<Guid>, IAudit, IBaseEntity
{ 
    public virtual CommonPersonProfile PersonProfile { get; protected set; } = default!; 
}
public abstract class CommonPersonProfile : IBaseEntity, IAudit
{
    public Guid? UserAccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual CommonUserAccount? UserAccount { get; set; }
}
```

Theses 2 classes are later inhereted by other projects

```
public class UserAccount : CommonUserAccount
{
    public virtual Employee? Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual PersonProfile PersonProfile => (PersonProfile)base.PersonProfile;
}

public class PersonProfile: CommonPersonProfile
{
    public new UserAccount? UserAccount => (UserAccount?)base.UserAccount;
}
```

With that im facing a problem
When I try to navigate from UserAccount to Employee, I can't. EF does not recognize that its the inherited type, It thinks its handling the CommonUserAccount and not the inherited type.

Example of a query that fails

```
dbContext.PeopleProfiles
         .Include(t => t.UserAccount)
           .ThenInclude(t => t.Employee)
```

> The expression 't.Employee' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation,
> since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To
> target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t =>
> ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as
> Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by
> composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take
> operations. For more information on including related data, see
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

Is there a way to make this work?

Minimal reproducible example
https://github.com/zamecki/SharedEntityExample

Comment: We need a [mcve]

Comment: Here it is
https://github.com/zamecki/SharedEntityExample

Comment: Ah, better, i was wondering how this would work/ compile in the first place, as you seem to be hiding a property of the base class. This is not possible without `new`... that's not in the code in your question, but it is in the example. Very hard to help people when they don't give you correct code

Comment: And what's the issue with doing it the way it's described in the error message? `dbContext.PeopleProfiles.Include(t => t.UserAccount).ThenInclude(t => ((UserAccount)t.)Employee)`?

Comment: Did that worked for you, when I try that it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've found a solution is very verbose but it works.

Basically my Shared project needs to handle generic types

```
public abstract class CommonUserAccount<TUserAccount, TPersonProfile> : IdentityUser, IBaseEntity
    where TPersonProfile : CommonPersonProfile<TPersonProfile, TUserAccount>
    where TUserAccount : CommonUserAccount<TUserAccount, TPersonProfile>
{
    public virtual TPersonProfile PersonProfile { get; protected set; } = default!;
}

public interface ICommonDbContext<TUserAccount, TPersonProfile>
    where TUserAccount : CommonUserAccount<TUserAccount, TPersonProfile>
    where TPersonProfile : CommonPersonProfile<TPersonProfile, TUserAccount>
{
    public DbSet<TUserAccount> UserAccounts { get; }
    public DbSet<TPersonProfile> PeopleProfiles { get; }
}
```

I have updated the project too, so anyone can use as an example

Comment: Makes sense. That's probably also why [`IdentityDbContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identitydbcontext) is a generic class.